# Isolated DC/DC converter application circuit / usage

Tags: power, converter, 12v, 5v, isolated

I'm trying to find a basic application circuit schematic for an isolated DC/DC converter – this one specifically: [DCWN03E-12](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/DCWN03E-12?qs=5aG0NVq1C4zkYbAc05YQBw==) – but I'm having no luck so far. The thing that led me to this particular product was searching for reasonably compact device that could do:

1. ~5VDC Vin
2. ±12VDC Vout
3. At least ~125mA per output

I plugged those parameters into a filter with a few other logistic requirements and that converter seemed the most bang for my buck. Seems its usual use case is in medical equipment; I have no need for the current isolation a medical device would call for, this just seemed to fit my spec perfectly.

The [datasheet](http://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=797) is sparse – I scoured it for details but the closest thing to an application circuit on there is a pinout diagram with the terminals labelled. I [foolishly] assumed this meant: hook your + and - up to 5V, get ±12V out plus a common ground. I can see this is likely not the case now because my multimeter reads a flat 0v on both outputs. Here's a basic schema of how it's hooked up:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNC1lq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I had a sinking feeling that nothing could be so simple, and now I think that feeling was right. No inductor? Output capacitors? Or is there something I'm missing here? Another datasheet perhaps?

Comment: You're right that there is nothing else in the specification sheet. You could add in the pin numbers for us to double-check. Check the input voltage hasn't collapsed with the startup surge.

Comment: No load or cap required. But may add up to 1000uF max for transients. It should work from 4.5~9V input and 3W max.

Comment: Okay, I've labelled the pins – they match up to the ones on the datasheet for sure. As far as startup goes, the 5V droops by precisely 0.01V when I plug it into the converter. It certainly doesn't collapse though.

Comment: maybe it is something stupid like having to connect pins 9 and 16 together

Comment: For the record: That is not a medical supply, even though it could probably be used as an auxiliary supply inside medical equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these commodity DC:DC are "plug and play" with some nominal input and output capacitance.

This particular device is surprisingly similar to the outline championed by Traco

https://assets.tracopower.com/20190124103907/TEN3/documents/ten3-datasheet.pdf

and thus the application notes for a comparable DC:DC is a good place to start: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/687/ten8wi-application-536504.pdf

Comment: You're right, that device looks almost pin-for-pin – good find. Now THAT's a datasheet. I'm going to need some time to look over these application circuits, but from a cursory glance, it looks like some designs do use external inductors, no? (Edit: actually those look like test circuits on second inspection)

Comment: Okay, accepting this as the answer due to that datasheet providing the first configuration that has worked for me! Seems that capacitor loading is necessary for startup (a minimal one at least) – the schematic with two 1uF on the input and a couple of 1nF running parallel between the respective + and - Vins and Vouts is what got it to start for me.

Answer (score 0):

That should be correct, however note that the 16 and 9 are connected internally.

If you're not seeing any output voltage, check obvious things such as input polarity and that your multimeter is reading DC correctly (measure the input voltage with your multimeter).

Do note that the pinout is show from the **bottom** which is a bit unusual these days, but it's clearly marked on the datasheet.

---

Generally you don't need any external components for it to function- however to meet some EMC requirements you may need to add an LC input filter. This particular model is stated to require no minimum load to remain in regulation, which is not always the case.

Comment: Yep, all good there – they were also consumer-friendly enough to even print the polarities right on the housing! Lovely. All pins do match the datasheet and should be accounted for

Comment: I guess you have to consider trying another unit at this point.